# Legend in a world map using Plotly doesn't show up when there is a colorbar

Tags: r, plotly

I am using Plotly in R. I want to create a world map and have two legends that will show distinct values. The first is the colour which corresponds to the number of papers published in each country. The second corresponds to the number of rootstocks used in each paper. These dots get bigger as there are more rootstocks used in the paper. Therefore, I would like to display a legend that shows what size fits the number of rootstocks.

However, it seems like the colour bar doesn't allow me to add values. When I remove this feature, the rootstocks legend works. I tried many different codes, also trying to do it with ggplot, but didn't succeed.

Here's my code, which will be followed by my data sets.

```
fig_jittered <- plot_geo(occurence) %>%
  layout(
    geo = list(
      showframe = TRUE,
      showcoastlines = TRUE,
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("darkgrey"),
      coastlinecolor = toRGB("black"),
      coastlinewidth = 0.5,
      lataxis = list(
        range = c(-55, 80),
        showgrid = FALSE
      ),
      lonaxis = list(
        range = c(-130, 160),
        showgrid = FALSE
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~count, color = ~count, colors = 'GnBu',
    text = ~COUNTRY, locations = ~code,
    marker = list(
      line = list(width = 0.5, color = "black")
    ),
    colorbar = list(title = "Number of papers published in each country", x = 1, y = 0.92)
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "scattergeo",
    lat = ~duse_no_dupplicats$lat_jittered, 
    lon = ~duse_no_dupplicats$lon_jittered,
    text = ~paste("Title: ", duse_no_dupplicats$title, "<br>Number of Rootstocks: ", duse_no_dupplicats$n_rootstock),
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(
      size = duse_no_dupplicats$dotsize_rootstock,
      symbol = "circle",
      color = "lightgrey",
      line = list(width = 1.5, color = "black")
    ),
    name = "Number of Rootstocks" # Add the legend label
  ) %>% 
  layout(
    title = "With jittered locations",
    legend = list( # Customize the legend position and appearance
      x = 0.05,
      y = 0.95,
      bgcolor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
      bordercolor = "black",
      borderwidth = 1
    )
  )

fig_jittered
```

**duse_no_dupplicats**

```
> dput(dusecut)
structure(list(id = c("1", "5", "10", "20", "21", "24", "25", 
"47", "58", "65", "68", "76", "83", "91", "103", "114", "116", 
"124", "127", "134", "135", "140", "141", "142", "145", "146", 
"174", "176", "180", "184", "188", "195", "208", "214", "216", 
"219", "222", "233", "249", "268"), lat_jittered = c(38.7377064359404, 
43.5761112164898, 37.9235031866915, 46.3098119040726, 36.5433768246047, 
33.7332840405519, 43.5035202752525, 44.7743270278773, 44.2681201993407, 
32.7704741151927, 34.0638900351183, 29.4918581168696, 48.3634134447124, 
46.9264395307103, 44.9000974477011, 50.0297460009899, -33.9590650219929, 
40.0440757318027, 47.8230118127686, 38.5980070016817, 37.1718596254961, 
-23.126341973152, 39.3257486161124, -9.22739536766893, -9.06022982656411, 
-20.3531972613832, 38.4468812217009, 38.7332140110433, 41.4678715980339, 
-34.1984225050714, -29.2180914001753, 44.0357768001092, 47.6772796015891, 
-34.3220146662689, 30.8555836620263, 42.8991637902538, 43.9426254258141, 
50.0253479496291, 43.9733679219306, 38.2798062185569), lon_jittered = c(-8.32537908562589, 
12.0947568336135, -121.691289428227, -119.075707938975, -118.580631370821, 
73.3190522662625, 12.1431015449209, -0.146355702619443, 86.4102098408073, 
51.5930024228714, -116.740621781656, 80.6078221716285, 16.6181140353805, 
16.6316830731611, 0.251698475820558, 7.22708447587718, 18.0598971270631, 
116.675036072787, 16.7021728935854, -120.951964736247, -94.7868793825128, 
-46.3831338794722, 118.427028340939, -39.6900623886666, -39.8427074421888, 
-49.7928484643629, -122.005469751341, -7.52678108194903, 15.8199758732707, 
141.563458767373, -51.1325258902965, 4.46389363309673, 17.2382388971558, 
142.851770006896, 33.9525991678717, -85.1173569477579, 87.8841016072193, 
7.24152549942959, 4.48478443562873, -121.569625517062), n_rootstock = c(NA, 
2, 15, 5, NA, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 
2, 7, 2, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5, 7, 15, 8, NA, 5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 14), 
    dotsize_rootstock = c(NA, 1.5, 11.25, 3.75, NA, 3.75, 1.5, 
    1.5, 3.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3, 2.25, 3.75, 2.25, 1.5, 1.5, 3.75, 
    0.75, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 5.25, 1.5, 4.5, 1.5, 6, 0.75, 3.75, 5.25, 
    11.25, 6, NA, 3.75, 1.5, 1.5, 2.25, 1.5, 0.75, 10.5)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 
33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 49L, 52L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Occurence**

```
> dput(occurence)
structure(list(COUNTRY = c("Australia", "Austria", "Brazil", 
"China", "Czech Republic", "Egypt", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
"Hungary", "India", "Iran", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Pakistan", 
"Portugal", "South Africa", "Spain", "Turquie", "United States"
), code = c("AUS", "AUT", "BRA", "CHN", "CZE", "EGY", "FRA", 
"DEU", "GRC", "HUN", "IND", "IRN", "ISR", "ITA", "JPN", "PAK", 
"PRT", "ZAF", "ESP", "TUR", "USA"), count = c(5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 
18L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

If someone could help me it would be great as I am a little a little lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a second color bar for the 2nd trace, you need to do two things, 1: you need to assign a variable `color` and 2: you need to assign `colorscale` a *color scale*. If you have a static color, you won't have a *color scale*.

Check out this variation of that second trace- I've annotated lines I've added and commented out.

BTW, you had layout called two times, I consolidated them into one call.

```
library(plotly)

plot_geo(occurence) %>%
  layout(
    geo = list(
      showframe = TRUE, showcoastlines = TRUE, showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrycolor = toRGB("darkgrey"),
      coastlinecolor = toRGB("black"),
      coastlinewidth = 0.5,
      lataxis = list(range = c(-55, 80), showgrid = FALSE),
      lonaxis = list(range = c(-130, 160), showgrid = FALSE)
    ), title = "With jittered locations") %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~count, color = ~count, colors = 'GnBu',
    text = ~COUNTRY, locations = ~code,
    marker = list(
      line = list(width = 0.5, color = "black")
    ),
    colorbar = list(title = "Number of papers<br />published in<br />each country",
                    x = 1, y = 1, len = .5) # longer to give space for title
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = duse_no_dupplicats, type = "scattergeo", mode = "markers", 
    lat = ~lat_jittered, lon = ~lon_jittered,
    text = ~paste("Title: ", duse_no_dupplicats$title, "<br>Number of Rootstocks: ", 
                  duse_no_dupplicats$n_rootstock),
    color = ~dotsize_rootstock,                               # <<--- I'm NEW!
    marker = list(
      size = ~dotsize_rootstock,
      symbol = "circle",
      # color = "lightgrey",                                  # <<--- I've got to go
      colorscale = 'Greys',                                   # <<--- I'm NEW!
      line = list(width = 1.5, color = "black"),
      colorbar = list(title = "Root Stock", x = 1, y = .3, len = .4) # <<--- I'm NEW!
    ),
    name = "Number of Rootstocks" # Add the legend label
  )
```

[image]

Another option is to add a chart for the root stock data.

In this version there are two plots, one is the geo, similar to what you've already created, the other will *look* like a legend, but it is really another plot.

```
plt <- plot_geo(occurence) %>%
  layout(margin = list(t = 100, b = 40, r = 100, l = 40),
         geo = list(
           showframe = TRUE, showcoastlines = TRUE, showland = TRUE,
           landcolor = toRGB("white"),
           countrycolor = toRGB("darkgrey"),
           coastlinecolor = toRGB("black"),
           coastlinewidth = 0.5,
           lataxis = list(range = c(-55, 80), showgrid = FALSE),
           lonaxis = list(range = c(-130, 160), showgrid = FALSE)
         ), title = "With jittered locations"#,
                     # NEW ----   remove all legend specifics 
         # legend = list( # Customize the legend position and appearance
         #   x = 0.05, y = 0.95, bgcolor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
         #   bordercolor = "black", borderwidth = 1)
         ) %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~count, color = ~count, colors = 'GnBu',
    text = ~COUNTRY, locations = ~code,
    marker = list(
      line = list(width = 0.5, color = "black")
    ),
    colorbar = list(title = "Number of papers<br />published in<br />each country",
                    x = 1, y = 1, len = 1) # longer to give space for title
  ) %>%
  add_trace(showlegend = F,            # make sure to specify!
    type = "scattergeo",
    lat = ~duse_no_dupplicats$lat_jittered, 
    lon = ~duse_no_dupplicats$lon_jittered,
    text = ~paste("Title: ", duse_no_dupplicats$title, "<br>Number of Rootstocks: ", duse_no_dupplicats$n_rootstock),
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(
      size = duse_no_dupplicats$dotsize_rootstock,
      symbol = "circle",
      color = "lightgrey",
      line = list(width = 1.5, color = "black")
    )
  )
rg <- range(duse_no_dupplicats$dotsize_rootstock, na.rm = T) # range of sizes 
ls <- seq(ceiling(rg[1]), ceiling(rg[2]), length.out = 5)    # make an even seq

# create markers by range of sizes in root stock, showlegend = F; colorbar = NO
plt2 <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = 1, y = ls, 
                showlegend = F, color = ls,
                marker = list(sizeref = 0.1, sizemode = "area", size = ls, 
                              colorscale = "Greys",
                              line = list(color = "black", width = 1))) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = F, showline = F, zeroline = F, showticklabels = F), 
         yaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F, tickvals = ls, 
                      ticktext = ls, tickmode = "array")) %>% hide_colorbar()

subplot(plt2, plt, widths = c(.2, .8)) %>% 
  layout(annotations = list(     # add title to first plot (one that looks like legend)
    list(xref = "x1", yref = "y1", x = 1, y = 13, showarrow = F,
         text = "<br />Number of Root Stock", font = list(size = 14))
  ))  # show me!
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help on this! Unfortunately, once the second legend is regarding the size of the dots and the color should be uniform everywhere. Do you know how to do this? Also it seems that when the legend is on the left side, I loose access to the interactive feature of the map, which I value a lot. Could you help me on this ?